# How do I check if I got a JSON Obj or a possible JavaScript array/obj? (Without using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, http

I'm supposed to receive either of the following sets after a GET:

```
{
    "John": {"status":"Wait","number":1 },"Cody": {"status":"Active", "number":"2"}
}
```

**OR**

```
{
    John: {status:'Wait',number:1}, Cody: {status:'Active', number:2}
}
```

The first option is a valid JSON object, the 2nd option is not.  I already tried the approach below based from what I found after searching for a couple of hours, but it' doensn't work on the 2nd option.  JSON.parse is letting the 2nd option through as correct.  And then it errors out once I try to access the children.

```
try
{
   var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
}
catch(e)
{
   alert('invalid json');
}
```

Comment: You should look into jQuery's $.parseJSON() method

Comment: If what you have is a string (I can't tell from the code you posted), you can use `eval` as a last resort in the `catch` clause.

Comment: Would it be at all possible to convince the owners of server to always output JSON rather than mixing in JavaScript?

Comment: @RUJordan, let's say we cannot use jQuery (I updated the title too).

JonathanLonowski, the owners say that they are going to give me a JSON in the 2nd option (which is an incorrect JSON -- nonetheless, it's what they're going to provide me).

Comment: couldn't you try to search by regex for '\{\s"' for instance, which would be a beginning for some valid JSON string?

Comment: @bfavaretto Using `eval` on a string you receive in a GET parameter?

Comment: @ayjay: As Ingo alludes to, if they give you JS object literals instead of JSON your only option is to `eval`. Be aware that this makes your code **vulnerable by design**, as you will be executing whatever comes in and are essentially at the mercy of whoever responds to the HTTP request. I consider this unacceptable and would let them know in no uncertain terms. Here the choice is yours, but you should know where you are going.

Comment: You might try using [`json5`](https://github.com/aseemk/json5). As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10784644), the library is a slightly more relaxed JSON parser that should be capable of parsing JavaScript Object literals as well without allowing all that `eval()` will.

Comment: If `JSON.parse` is letting through the second string as well, then you have a flawed implementation - it should not work. Switch your JSON library.

Comment: `JSON.parse is letting the 2nd option through as correct. And then it errors out once I try to access the children.` I cannot reproduce this. Can you jsfiddle.net it?

Comment: @Bergi, you're right: http://jsfiddle.net/ayjay/phZUS/  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @ayjay No that jsfiddle is not quite right, here. http://jsfiddle.net/mLUt5/