# d3.js forced layout graph: parse String to link-array

Tags: json, d3.js, vaadin, force-layout

I am referring to this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292 ,
specifically to these beautiful lines of code:

```
var links = [
  {source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "licensing"},
  ...
  {source: "Nokia", target: "Qualcomm", type: "suit"}
];

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});
```

I'd like to know what data format **'var links'** here has, and how I would parse the following java string (with essentially the same content)

```
String someLinks = "[{source: \"Microsoft\", target: ... }, ...]"
```

into something equal to the javascript **'var links'** above, from which I can then create the graph.

I've tried

```
var links = JSON.parse( string );
```

But that doesn't do the job... **'var links'** doesn't seem to be JSON?
EDIT: Or should I use a different java format, e.g. some kind of Array? (Doesn't have to be a String)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "what data format" -- the data format is right there! How does the JSON parsing not do the job?

Comment: var links = JSON.parse(someLinks); throws an exception ====>               SEVERE: Exception caught: (SyntaxError) : JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is JSON in a string. Since JSON is simply JavaScript, you might be able to simply "run" the code to create the corresponding data structure. So try

```
var links = eval(someLinks)
```

Even though I have the suspicion if we take a step back, things might be handled differently and you wouldn't need `eval` in the first place (since it's generally considered bad style)

Answer (score 1):

Your value in `String someLinks` is no valid JSON.  It lacks the quotes on the attribute names.  JSON is more pedantic than javascript itself.

```
JSON.parse('[{"source":"A"},{"source":"B"}]')
```

will work (note the `"` around `source`.

Also you should avoid writing "protocols" by hand.  If you need to build a JSON string in javascript, you can use

```
JSON.stringify([{source:'A'},{source:'B'}])
```

Note that JSON e.g. also escapes `/` for security reasons. An oversight like this can quickly end in errors or worse.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I need to recieve an object from a java class... with all the escaping that indeed seems increaingly difficult.

Comment: @user3641140 then use a library on the java end of things.  there are plenty of them and the results are relyable.

Comment: Alright. Would that be much better than using eval() though? (And why?)

Comment: @user3641140 if the string in ``someLinks`` is cast in stone, then you might get further tips from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517/parsing-relaxed-json-without-eval.  But if you are creating on e.g. server side, then you might be better off using JSON.