# convert string in given format to knockout observable array

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

I have the following string comming from server (as part of object):

```
...
SelectValues: "[{displayName: "Not selected", id: 0},{displayName: "Client", id: 1},{displayName: "Industry", id: 2},{displayName: "Country", id: 3}]"
...
```

I am using mapping pluging:

```
var ItemModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

}
```

As a result all items are created properly, except `SelectValues`. SelectValues should be observable array (each array item should have two properties `id` & `displayName`). Later I will use `SelectValues` for dropdown.

The problem is that it is returned as `String` and not as `Array`.

The question is whether I can somehow deal with it on client side (without changing format on server side)?

I probably can create `SelectValuesComputed` as `ko.computed` and somehow convert SelectValues to array (how?).

Comment: Did you try parsing the string? using `ko.utils.parseJSON(data)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is invalid JSON string you have in your property, see [documentation](http://json.org/) (property names should be in quotes). But, having the condition that you cannot change the server code, you can use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function to get your object and then use it in mapping like this:

```
var ItemModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;   
    var mapping = {
        "SelectValues": {
            create: function(options){
                return ko.mapping.fromJS(eval(options.data));
            }
        }
    };
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self);
}
```

See working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/hssdf811/). Although this might seem like the simpliest way to workaround the problem, I would strongly recommend you though to get a valid JSON string instead of using eval (or [regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517/parsing-relaxed-json-without-eval)) to get your object.

Comment: What if I add " to properties? What would be difference with yoru code suggested above?

Comment: No, you still need the mapping to process your property, but then you would just use the following: `return ko.mapping.fromJSON(options.data);`. But currently it won't work because of invalid JSON.

Comment: This is a bit out of scope - but how then to send this object back to server? Currently when I am doing ko.mapping.toJS it sends it correctly, but on server it converts it to null and not string (.NET)?

Comment: @renathy This is pretty ugly, but the only thing that comes to my mind is to keep your original value untouched, and use another observableArray for parsed items. See updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/hssdf811/2/).