# Trying to convert json response string variable to object but failed

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

The json response return (from ajax function) :

`{
   "shoe_products":"{name: 'nike pegasus 35',data: [56.00,43.00,32.00], stack: 'Nike'},{name: 'adidas ultraboost',data: [32.00,34.00,35.00,0,55.0], stack: 'Adidas'}"
}`

This is string after I debug it using `alert(typeof data.myjson)`. The problem is, I can't convert it to object.

```
var myobj = JSON.parse(data.shoe_products); //this will return Unexpected token n in JSON at position 1
```

But if I do the code below, it return as an object.

```
var test = [{"shoe_products":"{name: 'nike pegasus 35',data: [56.00,43.00,32.00], stack: 'Nike'},{name: 'adidas ultraboost',data: [32.00,34.00,35.00,0,55.0], stack: 'Adidas'}"}];
```

**Ajax function**

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlLinkHere,
            data: { "year" : year },
            success: function(data) {

                var myobj = JSON.parse(data.shoe_products);

            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: In [Json](http://json.org/), property names need to be surrounded by quotes. e.g. `{"name":...}` instead of `{name:...}`

Comment: in my case, how do I convert all these property names with double quotes?

Comment: If you can control the format of the source data, I'd try to make sure it produces valid Json. If not, you'll need a non-standard parser. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517/parsing-relaxed-json-without-eval).

Comment: I could control the format of the source data, but it will be ugly though because I will use str_replace for each of the property name (name, data, stack)

Comment: seems like i am still unable to convert to object after changing all the property name with double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could consider the following:

1. Surround any "key" in the json string with double quotes via this: `.replace(/([a-z]+)\w*c/gi, "\"$1\":")`. The idea here is to match any string that's followed by `:` (which we consider to be a key) and wrap those matches with the double quotes.
2. Next, surround the string from step 1 with `[` and `]`, seeing that the data in `shoe_products` is actually an array (there are multiple objects in the `shoe_products` string that are separated by a `,`)

So, something along these lines:

```js
// Your input data
var test = [{"shoe_products":"{name: 'nike pegasus 35',data: [56.00,43.00,32.00], stack: 'Nike'},{name: 'adidas ultraboost',data: [32.00,34.00,35.00,0,55.0], stack: 'Adidas'}"}];

var shoe_products = test[0].shoe_products;

// The shoe_products data is organised as a list of data, so surround with [] brackets
// to achieve valid JSON array
var validJsonString = '[' + shoe_products
// Surround all json keys with double quotes. These are matched by any string followed by
// a colon
.replace(/([a-z]+)\w*:/gi, "\"$1\":") 
// Replace any other single quote with double quotes
.replace(/'/gi,'"') + ']'


var jsonObject = JSON.parse(validJsonString);

console.log(jsonObject)
```