# Parsing Multi-Level JSON Output Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, parsing

***EDITED WITH UPDATED OUTPUT***
I was able to use the request module which now provides me with verified standard JSON output.  See below output:

```html
 const respBody = {
  "items" : [ {
    "id" : "T0lDX0J1aWxkX0FydGlmYWN0czpmODk4YjM5MDNjYjk5YzU5NjgzNTk3ZWRjNWFmZjliYw",
    "repository" : "Build_Artifacts",
    "format" : "raw",
    "group" : "/",
    "name" : "myFile.zip",
    "version" : null,
    "assets" : [ {
      "downloadUrl" : "http://localhost:8081/repository/Build_Artifacts/myFile.zip",
      "path" : "myFile.zip",
      "id" : "T0lDX0J1aWxkX0FydGlmYWN0czphNDc1N2JjYWE2MmI2MzA2MDdlMTA1NGE4NTk1MDQ1OQ",
      "repository" : "OIC_Build_Artifacts",
      "format" : "raw",
      "checksum" : {
        "sha1" : "040e517528c05ca335a38e98c7ab8673773314bd",
        "sha512" : "652e624873da778dce4bc417cacfead12bdd2ad01e9f7f77cba80270caa0f99caa09d4fb53f584a4da9991186f78bd7b55da1e4ed3f22e026b8333dd332b3b83",
        "sha256" : "b66805d15702505f708b90f6e1169c79390d59b9f8cadc9ab1852f48eeabbfe2",
        "md5" : "60fdd406e026330c2cfbec3e15e05414"
      }
    } ]
  }]
}
```

I was able to parse what I needed with "respbody.items[0].name"

Comment: JSON.parse is to convert string to object . You have already object u can't use parse method here. U need to convert this object to expected one. So u should also share expected output in question

Comment: Updated with expected output....sorry about that forgot to add it...

Comment: Okey u want to take only name but another problem this is not a valid json object. Where do u take it ?

Comment: I updated the question with the JS code I am using to get to the point I am at.  I didn't initially put that into the question because I was thinking the solution was something simple I was missing.....

Answer (score 0):

That isn't the JSON standard covered by `JSON.parse()`. The easiest way to get the object would be to use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```js
let array = global
  .eval("[{foo: 'bar', name: 'value'}]")
  .map(item => {
    return {name: item.name};
  });

// will output: [{name: "value"}]
console.log(array);
```

But that would be totally unsave, like MDN writes:

> **Warning:** Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use `eval()`. See [Never use eval()!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!), below.

A better way would be using [JSON5](https://github.com/aseemk/json5), which also supports the object notation of ES5 JavaScript. It is also available over npm:

#### https://www.npmjs.com/package/json5

For more information about that see the question "[Parsing "relaxed" JSON without eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517/parsing-relaxed-json-without-eval/10784644)".

Comment: I tried this earlier and couldn't get it to work.  Using your example my output still looks like [{name: "undefined"}]......this is due to not being able to get to the "name" element.....

Comment: @Seth0080 Ok, and what am I supposed to to with that info? That is not reproducible for me... Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this and see if you can reproduce the issue there? Please read the ["How do I ask?" Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I used "request" module instead of "fetch" and the return was verified JSON output.  After that I was able to parse using "respBody.items[0].name" and returned the output I was expecting.  You were correct, my issues was my initial output was not in standard JSON which caused my issues.