# how convert string arrays of arrays into normal arrays without using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript

im currently woking on replicating a json parse like function but i have been unable to handle nested string arrays like :  `'"[a, [b, c, e, g], n]"'`.
I've tried thing like split, replace and and index of to try to target but have been unable to get a correct output. the most recent one being :
`string.slice(1, string.length - 1).replace(/['"]+/g, '').replace(/[' '']+/g, '').split(',')`;

Comment: Are `a, b, c, e, g, n` supposed to be strings or variables?

Comment: @DanielF no where does the OP say it is using JSON.parse....

Comment: check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) documentation. There is polyfill section if you want to try your custom implementation.

Comment: Typically with building a parser you are not splitting and replacing and finding indexes. It is unclear what the expected result is supposed to be.

Comment: you have mentioned that have to handle with string arrays like '"[a, [b, c, e, g], n]"' but what is your expected result?

Comment: This looks more like a job for a recursive CSV parser.

Comment: Not great, but if `a, b, c, e, g, n` are variables, and you want the values, then `eval(eval('"[a, [b, c, e, g], n]"'))`.

Comment: https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-javascript/

Comment: If possible, please fix the source of the string to get a [valid JSON string](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). If it is not in your control, this question has some libraries in answers. You could try those: [Parsing “relaxed” JSON without eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517)

Comment: Not sure if OP promises any element of the array will never be one complicated object.

Comment: *"replicating a json parse like function"*: but your example input is not valid JSON. So what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for arrays containing either single characters, or containing other arrays containing only single characters.

```js
const string = '"[a, [b, c, e, g], n]"'.slice(2, -2);
const array = [];
let currArr = array;

for (const char of string) {
  /[a-z]/.test(char) && currArr.push(char);
  /\]/.test(char) && (currArr = array);
  if (/\[/.test(char)) {
    currArr = [];
    array.push(currArr);
  }
}

console.log(array); // [ 'a', [ 'b', 'c', 'e', 'g' ], 'n' ]
```

When it encounters an opening bracket `[` it pushes a new array and pushes all future letters into that array until it encounters a closing bracket `]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a rudimentary tokenization parser. You have 4 conditions. This utilizes recursion, so it should work for deeply-nested data.

- Opening square-bracket
- White-space
- Comma
- Character

Keep in mind that it only scans 1 letter at a time, for a contiguous sequence of letters, you will need to consume them as chunks.

```js
let text = '[a, [b, [c, e], g], n]';

const parse = (input, bucket=[]) => {
  if (input.length === 0) return bucket;
  let token = input.charAt(0);
  switch (token) {
    case '[':
      let end = input.lastIndexOf(']');
      bucket.push(parse(input.substring(1, end)))
      parse(input.substring(end + 1), bucket);
      break;
    case ' ':
    case ',':
      parse(input.substring(1), bucket);
      break;
    default:
      bucket.push(token);
      parse(input.substring(1), bucket);
  }
  return bucket;
}

console.log(parse(text)[0]) // Unwrap the first item
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```