# how can i make my function handle multiple string arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

i've been working for some homework in replicating a json parse like function and currently i wrote a function as follows :

```js
var arr = '[a, [a, bjng],  n]'
var intoArray = function(string) {
  if (string.length <= 2) {
    return [];
  }
  var resultsArr = [];
  var toJoin = [];
  var simpArr = string.slice(1, string.length - 1).replace(/['"]+/g, '').replace(/[' '']+/g, '').split(',');
  for (var a = 0; a < simpArr.length; a++) {
    if (simpArr[a].includes('[')) {
      while (!simpArr[a].includes(']')) {
        toJoin.push(simpArr[a]);
        a++;
      }
    }
    if (simpArr[a].includes(']')) {
      toJoin.push(simpArr[a]);
    }
  }
  var joined = toJoin.join(',')
  var joint = joined.slice(1, joined.length - 1).replace(/['"]+/g, '').replace(/[' '']+/g, '').split(',')
  for (var a = 0; a < simpArr.length; a++) {
    if (!toJoin.includes(simpArr[a])) {
      resultsArr.push(simpArr[a])
    }
    if (simpArr[a] === toJoin[0]) {
      resultsArr[a] = joint
    }
  }

  return resultsArr
};

console.log(intoArray(arr))
```

when run it converts this string `'[a, [a, bjng],  n]'`(this is all just one big string) into `[ 'a', [ 'a', 'bjng' ], 'n' ]` (this is an array with multiple string and another array inside, this is the desired behavior). However when the sample string has more than one array inside of it like `'[a, [a, bjng],[c] , n]'` the result is that it is taken as just one bigger array like `[ 'a', [ 'a', 'bjng]', '[c' ], 'n' ]` (notice how instead of creating two array it thinks that `'[a' trough 'c]'` is one big array), i'm still learning so some insight would be much appreciated or if someone has some idea of how i can adapt it to handle multiple arrays!!! or perhaps a better implemntation?

Comment: You need to research "recursive descent parsing".

Comment: This is not a simple task, and doesn't seem like an appropriate assignment for a beginner class.

Comment: This isn't complicated ...

Answer (score 0):

Logic is identical to that of my last answer to your similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63178890/13378247), except it uses chunks of consecutive characters instead of individual characters in order to handle strings longer than `1`.

```js
const string = '[a, [a, bjng],  n]'.slice(1, -1);
const chunks = string.match(/\w+|[\[\]|,| ]/g);

const array = [];
let currArr = array;

for (const chunk of chunks) {
  /\w/.test(chunk) && currArr.push(chunk);
  chunk == ']' && (currArr = array);
  if (chunk == '[') {
    currArr = [];
    array.push(currArr);
  }
}

console.log(array); // [ 'a', [ 'a', 'bjng' ], 'n' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

@GirkovArpa made a good start, but as @Barmar already mentioned: you will need some kind of recursion if you want to process arbitrary (deeper) array structures correctly. Here is my (rudimentary) take on it:

```js
const string = '[a, [ [d,e,[f,g]], bjng], [c], n]';

function parse(str){
  function add2arr(a,p){ var c
    do c=p.shift()
    while( c && (/\w/.test(c)&&a.push(c) 
              || c==','
              || c=='[' &&a.push(add2arr([],p))) );
    return a
  }
  const parts = str.replace(/\s*/g,"").match(/\w+|[\[\],]/g);
  if(parts.shift()=='[') return add2arr([],parts);
}

console.log(parse(string))

// or, much simpler: use JSON.parse:

console.log(JSON.parse(string.replace(/(\w+)/g,'"$1"')));
```