# How to convert coordinate pair from string to array for google map polygon?

Tags: jquery, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I have a string of coordinate pairs that looks like this:

```
var path = { lat: 41.51663913751271, lng: -72.42501842191292}q{ lat: 41.522808462596736, lng: -72.33163463285042}q{ lat: 41.44410551903285, lng: -72.31996165921761}q{ lat: 41.43484006513872, lng: -72.41540538480355}q{ lat: 41.48475492271096, lng: -72.36665355374886},
```

I need to get it to look like this:

```
var coordinates = [
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 },
    { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
    { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 },
  ];
```

- I have complete control over the initial string so I can change the format, delimiters, etc.

What I have tried:

```
var polyCoords = path.split('q');
```

Which results in and is not what I need:

```
["{ lat: 41.51663913751271, lng: -72.42501842191292}", "{ lat: 41.522808462596736, lng: -72.33163463285042}", "{ lat: 41.44410551903285, lng: -72.31996165921761}", "{ lat: 41.43484006513872, lng: -72.41540538480355}", "{ lat: 41.48475492271096, lng: -72.36665355374886}", ""]
```

I have also tried JSON.parse(path); but that shows syntax errors.

Also, if it is helpful, this is how I am currently capturing the coordinates as a string:

```
polygon_boundary_coordinates += "{ lat: " + currentPolygon.getPath().getAt(i).lat() + ", lng: " + currentPolygon.getPath().getAt(i).lng() + "}q";
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After split, it resulted in array of stringified JSON and a redundant empty string, you just have to do two more steps, filter out empty string, and map and parse each of filtered element after that

```
var polyCoords = path
  .split('q')
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(coord => JSON.parse(coord))
```

Last but not least, the most important thing, prior to the above, is to make the stringified JSON's properties have quotes `""` surround them, for a proper `JSON.parse`

```
polygon_boundary_coordinates += "{ \"lat\": " + currentPolygon.getPath().getAt(i).lat() + ", \"lng\": " + currentPolygon.getPath().getAt(i).lng() + "}q";
```

```js
const splited = [
  '{ "lat": 41.51663913751271, "lng": -72.42501842191292}',
  '{ "lat": 41.522808462596736, "lng": -72.33163463285042}',
  '{ "lat": 41.44410551903285, "lng": -72.31996165921761}',
  '{ "lat": 41.43484006513872, "lng": -72.41540538480355}',
  '{ "lat": 41.48475492271096, "lng": -72.36665355374886}',
  "",
];

const coordinates = splited.filter(Boolean).map((coord) => JSON.parse(coord));

console.log(coordinates);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It would have taken me a while to figure all that out. I am not familiar enough with json.parse.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.
(Some parts take from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517/parsing-relaxed-json-without-eval)

```
let polyCoords = path.replace(/,\s*$/,"").split("q").map(cur=>JSON.parse(cur.replace(/(['"])?([a-z0-9A-Z_]+)(['"])?:/g, '"$2": ')))
```

I'll split this up and explain why each part is needed.

`path.replace(/,\s*$/,"")`

This removes the trailing comma from the initial data.

`.split("q")`

Splits into an array of strings.

The map will perform action on every element in the array.

`cur.replace(/(['"])?([a-z0-9A-Z_]+)(['"])?:/g, '"$2": ')`

This is needed because there are not double quotes around the keys of the initial string and it won't parse otherwise.

Note: hbg123's answer will work, but only if you can get the quotes around the keys. Otherwise you'll get an error when calling JSON.parse.