# How to parse a NON JSON STRING to a Object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with parsing a non-json object string to an actual object in javascript

the example string looks like:

```
let objString = '{ one: [1, 2, 3], num: 1 }';
```

what I want it to look like is

```
obj = { one: [1, 2, 3], num: 1 };
```

So far I have tried:

- JSON.stringify then JSON.parse
- JSON.parse
- eval

None of these work for rather obvious reasons but I am stuck at how to accomplish this, this is for a class I am writing to run and evaluate code, below is a snippet of the method in question.

```
compare() {
  const { testCaseInfo, stdout } = this;
  const expected = testCaseInfo.expected;
  if (this.err || stdout.length < 1) { return false };

  let parsedAnswer = stdout;
  parsedAnswer = parsedAnswer.split('\n').join('');
  
  /* Need help here, some edge case of Obj strings */
  if (parsedAnswer.indexOf('{')) {

  }
  // This works for everything else
  parsedAnswer = JSON.parse(parsedAnswer);

  this.output = parsedAnswer;
  
  return _.isEqual(parsedAnswer, expected);
}
```

Comment: This is a very X/Y problem. Possible, but I'd really really suggest considering an alternative method if feasible

Comment: Try replacing all ' to " like  `objectString.replace(/(['"])?([a-z0-9A-Z_]+)(['"])?:/g, '"$2": ');`

Comment: Do you have any control over how `objString` is generated? `JSON.parse('{ "one": [1, 2, 3], "num": 1 }')` works with quotes around the keys. If not, you may need to look at sanitizing your JSON. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517/parsing-relaxed-json-without-eval

Comment: @wahoowa the raw text is actually collected from the stdout of executing a file, so it has already comes as a string and not in JSON format. :(

Comment: @fortunee thank you for the idea, didnt work sadly.

Comment: How exactly does `eval` "not work"?

Comment: @Siguza It returns SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' : '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a really cheeky way to do it

```
let obj = {}
eval("obj =" + '{ one: [1, 2, 3], num: 1 }')
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in parentheses.

```
let objString = '{ one: [1, 2, 3], num: 1 }';
let obj = eval('(' + objString + ')');
```

Needless to say though, you should only ever `eval` things from trusted sources.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party but I've just run into this myself so I thought I would give it a quick search and this thread popped up. Anyway, I would rather use this:

```
let obj = new Function("return " + objString + ";")();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since using [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) is **security risk**. I would suggest you to try converting your string to a parsable JSON string then use `JSON.parse()` to parse.

```js
const keyFinderRegEX = /([{,]\s*)(\S+)\s*(:)/mg;
const convertedJSONString = '{ one: [1, 2, 3], num: 1 }'.replace(keyFinderRegEX, '$1"$2"$3');
const parsedObj = JSON.parse(convertedJSONString);

    console.log(parsedObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn your String into this format below and it should parse properly using JSON.parse()

```js
let objString = '{ "one": [1, 2, 3], "num": 1 }';

console.log(JSON.parse(objString));
```

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing this, I thought of this as an approach as but seems extremely difficult to actually develop a function to achieve this...

Comment: You could try something like this `JSON.parse('{ one: [1, 2, 3], num: 1 }'.replace(/([{,]\s*)(\S+)\s*(:)/mg, '$1"$2"$3'))`

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid using `eval`, you can check if your input strings always comply to [JSON5](https://json5.org/) format. It is less strict than traditional JSON and allows, e. g., not using quotes for key names definition, like in ECMAScript objects.

In order to parse JSON5 strings, use [JSON5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json5) npm package. Its API is the same as in the standard `JSON` object: you can just import it, write `JSON5.parse(objString)` and that's it.