# format json is not true

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a site that send me a json but this json has wrong format and I don't know what I should to do to convert this to the right format .
I want to use this to my python code.
this is my json that sent by site.

```js
{
  product_id: 11,
  user_id: 44,
  data: {
    "Wood shear wall design": {
      "Height of wall": { value: "4", unit: "ft" },
      "Length of wall": { value: "4", unit: "ft" },
      "Shear force": { value: "1000", unit: "lb" },
      "sheathing grade": {
        value: '{"id":1136,"item":"Sheathing","section_product_item":"30_77"}',
        unit: "N/A",
      },
      "sheathing material": {
        value: '{"id":1137,"item":"OBS","section_product_item":"30_77"}',
        unit: "N/A",
      },
      "sheathing type": {
        value: '{"id":1138,"item":"3\\/8","section_product_item":"30_77"}',
        unit: "N/A",
      },
      "stud size": {
        value: '{"id":1139,"item":"2_3","section_product_item":"30_77"}',
        unit: "N/A",
      },
      "number of nails": { value: "1", unit: "N/A" },
      "stud type": {
        value: '{"id":1143,"item":"6d","section_product_item":"30_77"}',
        unit: "N/A",
      },
      "nail spacing": {
        value: '{"id":1144,"item":"2","section_product_item":"30_77"}',
        unit: "ft",
      },
      "modulus of elasticity": { value: "1", unit: "psf" },
      "HD capacity": { value: "1", unit: "lb" },
      "HD deflection": { value: "1", unit: "in" },
      "number of opening": {
        value: '{"id":1149,"item":"0","section_product_item":"30_77"}',
        unit: "N/A",
      },
    },
  },
  type: 1,
  number_of_projects: 1,
}
```

I write this in every online formatter and insomnia but in all of them raise syntax error for json.
there is any library or function that can solve this problem?

Comment: Related: [Parsing "relaxed" JSON without eval](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9637517)

Comment: Strings should use double quotes in JSON. Whatever is providing this is broken, as it's not valid JSON.

Comment: You need to fix whatever is claiming that's JSON. It looks to be a valid Python literal (containing strings that actually _are_ JSON), but is certainly not JSON.

Comment: This question has been edited since first asked. The original data shown was a valid string representation of a Python dictionary. However, the data shown now is neither in that format nor is it valid JSON. You'll need to write your own parser. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The text you provided uses single-quotes (`'`), while json requires double-quotes (`"`). So to make it valid json you can probably take it as a string and just replace all `'` with `"`.

```
s = s.replace("'", '"')
```

Then do `json.loads(s)` to get a dictionary from the json. Just make sure that there aren't any single-quotes in the json that are actually meant to be single-quotes and don't just annotate keys.

Edit: on a second look the whole "json" looks pretty weird, are you sure this is supposed to be valid json?

Comment: thanks for your help. actually no I'm not sure. but if it was not a json will defferent?

Comment: If it's not json you cannot treat it like json and expect it to work. Where did you get the data?