# Convert String Object to real Object (without quotes)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm having some trouble converting an object of type string to a real object.

Here is my example (it's a string):

```
{ id: true,translations:{id: true,text: true,language:{id: true,languageCode: true}},createdAt: true }
```

When I JSON.Stringify it I get:

```
"{ id: true,translations:{id: true,text: true,language:{id: true,languageCode: true}},createdAt: true }"
```

And when I JSON.Parse it I get the same result as the example above, I also did console log the type of it and I get it's of type string

Any Ideas on how I should convert it to a real object?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can only JSON.parse a string that is in valid JSON format - which that isn't - in another question asked minutes ago, someone linked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517/parsing-relaxed-json-without-eval

Comment: You could use `eval()` but be aware of the security implications!

Comment: It's not valid JSON, so your only options are getting custom parser or resorting to wrapping it in `eval('(' + str + ')')`, or you can wrap the keys in your object with quotes.

Comment: The right solution - if possible - would be to go to the source of that broken string and fix it to give you proper JSON instead.

Comment: you should reformat your **string** object into **valid JSON format** , for example: instead of giving the string with `{id:.., text:..,..}` , you should use **double quotes** to specify keys in this way `{"id":...,"text":...,..}`
here is the full corrected case:
```
JSON.parse('{ "id": true, "translations":{"id": true,"text": true,"language":{"id": true,"languageCode": true} }, "createdAt": true }');
```

Comment: [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the easiest way to handle this is using the [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5) library

```js
const string="{ id: true,translations:{id: true,text: true,language:{id: true,languageCode: true}},createdAt: true }";
const object = JSON5.parse(string);
console.log(object)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/json5@2.2.1/dist/index.js"></script>
```